# How do I map List<T1> to List<T2> using LINQ (or otherwise)

Tags: c#, linq, list, extension-methods

Lately I've worked on some programs that involve translating objects across various data domains.  So I have a lot of mapping methods (sometimes as extension methods) for translating one type of object to another similar type in a different domain.  Often, I also need a way to translate a List<> to a List<> of said types.  This always involves having a method that simply creates a List<> of the target type, runs a foreach loop to add every element of the source List<> (but using the mapping method on each) and returning the new list.  It's feeling pretty repetitive and like there might be something built into the language to do this (perhaps in LINQ?).  I've looked at several similar issues involving List.ForEach() and the pros and cons of it (not what I'm looking for anyway).  I'll illustrate with some example code below.  Maybe there is no way to do what I want, and if that's the answer, then that's the answer, but I hope maybe there is.  Please note, this is obviously just example code and comments about my overall program design won't really add anything because this is a very small dummy version of the problem at hand.

```
class A
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string MemberCode { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string MemberCode { get; set; }

    // My custom mapping method
    public A MapToA()
    {
        return new A()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Email = this.Email,
            MemberCode = this.MemberCode
        };
    }

    // For list mapping, I have this, but I'd prefer
    // to do something else that could utilize my custom mapper.
    // Perhaps a built in LINQ method?
    public static List<A> MapToListOfA(List<B> listOfB)
    {
        List<A> listOfA = new List<A>();

        foreach (var b in listOfB)
        {
            listOfA.Add(b.MapToA());
        }

        return listOfA;
    }
}

// Class C shows what I currently do that I'd like to get
// away from:
class C
{
    public List<A> ListOfA { get; set; }
    // other properties unrelated to the problem

    // This is how I might use the MapToListOfA method,
    // but I'd rather have something better.
    public C(List<B> listOfB)
    {
        this.ListOfA = B.MapToListOfA(listOfB);
    }
}

// I'd like something more like this:
class D
{
    public List<A> ListOfA { get; set; }
    // other properties unrelated to the problem

    public D(List<B> listOfB)
    {
        // This doesn't compile, of course, but I hope
        // it illustrates what I'm intending to do:
        this.ListOfA = listOfB.Select(b => b.MapToA());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked AutoMapper??

Comment: You have a sound approach. Just add the call to .ToList().

Comment: I certainly do love the trolls on this site who downvote with no explanation. Please, troll, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and tell me which part I violated.  I suspect your problem with this question is "You should have already known the answer."  That's a great attitude to have at a QUESTION ASKING SITE. As much as I've loved this community for the positive people, these click-happy downvoters are a huge turn-off.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - No, I have not.  I'll check it out.  I do like to do the simple things simply and without libraries when possible, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// This doesn't compile, of course, but I hope
// it illustrates what I'm intending to do:
this.ListOfA = listOfB.Select(b => b.MapToA());
```

It doesn't compile because `listOfB.Select(b => b.MapToA())` produces an instance of `IEnumerable<A>` which is not assignable to `List<A>`.

Use `ToList` and it should compile fine

```
this.ListOfA = listOfB.Select(b => b.MapToA()).ToList();
```

Comment: Bonus info: Since most Mapping Methods are a `Func` (one input with non-void return), you can use the Mapping method itself in the `Select` statement instead of a lambda `func`.  `listOfB.Select(MapToA).ToList()`.

Comment: This was the first time I got the right answer so quickly that it wouldn't let me select it as the right answer for a few more minutes.

Comment: @ryanyuyu - That actually doesn't compile for me.  Is the issue that MapToA is a member of B and so must be called on an instance?

Comment: @ryanyuyu  That would work if it were  `public static A MapToA(B b)` instead of an instance method.

Comment: @bubbleking Ah yes.  That's it.  I'm just so used to having both mapping methods as `static` members (instead of instance ones).  I (erroneously) assumed that since the `List` map was static that the map for the individual object was also static.

Comment: @ryanyuyu - Thanks for the additional knowledge.  I'll take a look at if it makes sense for me to make these methods static for the added cleanliness of that Select().ToList() call.